# Invalid css in the most current version of chrome

Tags: html, css

I am coding a website and trying to make a background image but the image will not display. Any thoughts would help

```
nav{
background-image: url("/top-Bar.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Does a color show if you use a background color? It's possible the `nav` doesn't have any actual height. *100% of what?*

Comment: When you say "the most current version of Chrome", you say thay you tested on other versions of Chrome, or on other browsers and it worked? it may be the path to the image that is wrong.

Comment: Why is this "invalid CSS"? Do you mean "CSS not working"?

Comment: Look at the style inspector and examine the property `background-image`. What does it show?

Answer (score 4):

You're using `background-image`, when you should be using `background`:

```
nav{
  background: url("/top-Bar.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

EDIT: the above assumes the path to your image is correct of course.

Comment: It is still not displaying the image

Comment: Is the path to the image correct in url("/path/image.jpg")?

Comment: @samuidavid, there is nothing wrong with using "background-image" from my own knowledge.

Comment: `background-image` can't set the other properties the OP was trying to use. @samuidavid is correct. There is something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to samuidavid's answer... Your `<nav>` has no height. Either specify it in pixels or put the `<nav>` inside a `<div>` that has a height. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f2La1v6/).

```
div {
  height: 400px;
}

nav {
  background: url("http://animalpetdoctor.homestead.com/acat1.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Or put some (normal flow) content in that nav.